# about xml in c#

Tags: c#, xml, editing

At present I’m developing a registration form in which, when we click on the save button. It will get save in a xml file.
The details in the xml file should be displayed in the datagrid in separate window form. There are also three buttons. Edit, new and delete. 
     On clicking on edit button, the selected rows detail in gridview should display in the registration form. I don’t know how to do this.

By selecting a row, when we click on delete button , it should delete that particular record from the xml file. This also I’m not getting……….. please help me………………………………..

Regards,

Manikandan.S

Comment: Show us what have you done so far.

Comment: Homework or training document ?

Comment: Some further details could help.

Comment: is that Morse code there at the end? :-)

Answer (score 6):

This is readymade example By Zubair Ahmed and Scott Mitchell.
It displays and explains Editing of XML file with the use of Grid. I think this is what you need.

https://web.archive.org/web/20210513223010/http://aspnet.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/112603-1.aspx
[image: Edit xML with Grid]

Comment: You should've pasted the link as let google that for you. Hehe

Comment: :)
Exactly mate.. It was just second result. Now let me correct it.
So Let me google that for you (http://lmgtfy.com/?q=asp.net+grdivew+add%2Cupdate%2Cdelete+in+xml).

Comment: Of course is the second result. The first result is this question!

Answer (score 2):

Choose [DataSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset.aspx) class.

> SUMMARY:
>
> A DataSet can read and write data and
>   schema as XML documents. The data and
>   schema can then be transported across
>   HTTP and used by any application, on
>   any platform that is XML-enabled. You
>   can save the schema as an XML schema
>   with the WriteXmlSchema method, and
>   both schema and data can be saved
>   using the WriteXml method. To read an
>   XML document that includes both schema
>   and data, use the ReadXml method.
>
> In a typical multiple-tier
>   implementation, the steps for creating
>   and refreshing a DataSet, and in turn,
>   updating the original data are to:
>
> 1. Build and fill each DataTable in a
>      DataSet with data from a data source
>      using a DataAdapter.
> 2. Change the data in individual
>      DataTable objects by adding,
>      updating, or deleting DataRow
>      objects.
> 3. Invoke the GetChanges method to
>      create a second DataSet that
>      features only the changes to the
>      data.
> 4. Call the Update method of the
>      DataAdapter, passing the second
>      DataSet as an argument.
> 5. Invoke the Merge method to merge the
>      changes from the second DataSet into
>      the first.
> 6. Invoke the AcceptChanges on the
>      DataSet. Alternatively, invoke
>      RejectChanges to cancel the changes.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you use a serializeable object then you can work with an object in your form and whenever you want you can serialize it to a file or into a db field.
There's a utility called [XSD.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s(VS.80).aspx) that lets you build a serializeable object model from a xml.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is what you want to do at the end.
[XML - Insert/Update/Delete/Query](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/XmlDb.aspx)

Hope this helps! Please let me know!